# Generic UserControl Using Reflection and Generalization

Tags: c#, reflection, user-controls, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

in my project i've wrote some UserControl, i'm trying to reuse code as much as possible.
For each Model in my project i create an UserControl that shows the CRUD (a simple form )  and another that shows the List (listBox)

Is possible to Generalize that (for different types of Models with different attributes)? 
Using Generalizatione and Reflection is possible to create something like a generic UserControl_Crud and generic UserControl_List?

So in my page.xaml  i can use something like

```
<LUC:UserContro_Crud l x:Name="EmployeeUserControl_List" />
<LUC:UserContro_Crud l x:Name="CarsUserControl_List" />
<LUC:UserContro_Crud l x:Name="FruitUserControl_List" />
```

and in the code behind

```
EmployeeUserControl_List.MyProperty.ItemsSource = EmployeetList;
CarsUserControl_List.MyProperty.ItemsSource = CarstList;
//MyProperty give me back just the listbox from my UserControl
```

or

```
FruitUserControl_List.MyProperty.ItemsSource = EmployeetList;
```

to show 3 lists with differnt properties

---

@HighCore @Nate Diamond

In that way, for any kind of my Model, i have to make a particular template. For example CrudPersonTemplate  `

```
<!-- my crud-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyCrud">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="Code"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="edtCode" InputScope="Number" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="Name" />
            <TextBox x:Name="edtName" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="Sex" />
            <TextBox x:Name="edtSex" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

than (afeter registered it in the app.xaml as a resource) i can use it in Page.xaml just typing someting like

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyTemplate" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyCrud}" />
```

... but it's hard to manage field like "edtName" from page.xaml.cs  or not? i have to write more code than using UserControl to do that...
How can I manage as well as possible this field of my form?
where is the difference with UserControl? i have to bind manually the ContentTemplate...
I'm looking for a generic solution in page.xaml, in the "view" i just want to call a generic template/userControl, and "automatically" choose the relative layout according with the object type associated in page.xaml.cs  (i hope to explain it better, i apologize for my ignorance)

Comment: You're looking for [**DataTemplates**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx). XAML-based technologies already have that capability built-in.

Comment: But if i use DataTemplate how can i manage the object inside it?

Comment: You don't "manage" the "objects" inside DataTemplates in XAML-based technologies. A `DataTemplate` is the visual representation of a certain piece of data. In order to keep the UI and the underlying data in sync, you use [**DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What HighCore is saying is use the DataTemplate in a View (display). Have it bind to the location of the actual data, stored in a ViewModel object via data binding. This way, you can do all of your data manipulation and management from inside of the ViewModel.